# How get clear http-request data in component?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rxjs

Service get json-data from backend:

```
constructor(private http: Http) { };
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_todo2/users_list');
};
```

In the component, this data is processed:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsersData();
}
private getAllUsersData(): void {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
    data => {    
      this.allUsersData = JSON.parse(data.json());                 
      console.log(this.allUsersData);
    })
};
```

But i need processed this data in service. And i need get in component clear data:

```
private getAllUsersData(): void {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
    data => {    
      this.allUsersData = data;                 
      console.log(this.allUsersData);
    })
};
```

please help me.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/http (or, if you **must** use the deprecated client for some reason, https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html). Also note that `.json()` parses the response for you, so `JSON.parse(data.json())` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#httpclientget-returns-response-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Map** your data on service:

```
    getUsers(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_todo2/users_list')
                 .map(data => data.json());
    }
```

then:

```
private getAllUsersData(): void {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
    data => {    
      this.allUsersData = data;                 
      console.log(this.allUsersData);
    })
};
```